# Angular Apollo GraphQL Devtools tab invisible

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am developing an app using Angular 7 and Apollo GraphQL client and I am trying to use the [client devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm) for Chrome. If I understood the documentation correctly, the only thing that I have to do is to run my app in a non-production environment and the Apollo tab will appear on the Google Chrome development tools.

Unfortunately this is not happening. The Apollo Devtools icon appears on my browser, but the Apollo tab does not appear on the devtools.

Am I missing some configuration?

I also tried to force the devtools to appear, by adding: `connectToDevTools: true` to my GraphQL module (code below), but this didn't solve the problem.

```
const uri = environment.graphqlURL; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: true
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: I was having a CORS error when I tried to use my Graphql endpoint from the Angular development server (`localhost:4200`), so I created a proxy that pointed to my endpoint:

```
{
  "/graphql/*": {
    "target": "https://my-endpoint/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And changed the Graphql URL to: `http://localhost:4200/graphql`. With this I was able to solve my CORS issue, however it seems that the Apollo Dev Tools also uses the `/graphql` URI.

So I changed my proxy configuration to:

```
{
  "/stg_graphql/*": {
    "target": "https://my-endpoint/graphql",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/stg_graphql": ""
    }
  }
}
```

And pointed the graphql to: `http://localhost:4200/stg_graphql`. When I did this, everything started working.

Note: to run the development server with the proxy I am using: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json`.